# How to play rtsp live video in ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, rtsp, live-streaming

I am unable to get a suitable plugin to play rtsp video in my ionic app.tried CordovaStreamingMedia,cordova-rtsp but with no success.Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install this plugin in ionic project.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-streaming-media
npm install --save @ionic-native/streaming-media
```

=========================== .ts =================================

```
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions, StreamingAudioOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public toastCtrl: ToastController,
          private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) { }

startVideo(){
let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
  successCallback: () => { this.tost('Video played'); },
  errorCallback: (e) => { this.tost(JSON.stringify(e)); },
  orientation: 'landscape',
// orientation: 'portrait'
};

this.streamingMedia.playVideo(**'YOUR_LIVE_STREAMING_URL'**, options);
}

tost(message){

let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: message,
  duration: 3000
});
toast.present();
}
```

========================= HTML ======================

```
<ion-card>
<button ion-button (click)="startVideo()">Start Video</button>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: I have already tried this but with no success.It loads for some time with black screen and then gives MediaPlayerUnknown error.

Comment: My rtsp url looks like this:-rtsp://192.168.1.221/media/video1.My error message on console is Media Player Error: Unknown(1) - 2147483648